# Perform a curl request in python

Tags: python, json, rest, curl

I am trying to perform a curl request in python. My code is the following:

```
url = 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/api/common/learningSessions/588752bef1d4654173a43015'          
payload = json.loads(open("request.json"))         
headers = {'X-User-Path': '....', 'X-User-Token': '...')
r = requests.get(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Howver I am receiving in the second line the following error:

> TypeError: expected string or buffer (payload = json.loads(open("request.json")))

Any idea what this error is about?

Comment: But my json is validated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are opening file `open("request.json")` this will return `<open file 'request.json', mode 'r' at 0x108526810>`.

`json.loads` need string.

you can try

```
url = 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/api/common/learningSessions/588752bef1d4654173a43015'          
payload = json.loads(open("request.json").read())         
headers = {'X-User-Path': '....', 'X-User-Token': '...')
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

`file.read` will return file content instead of file object.

If you dont want to use `read` you can directly use `json.load` instead of `json.loads`

This is what I tried

```
echo '{}' > /tmp/test.json
cat /tmp/test.json
{}
```

Try to read same file.

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 19:40:32)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> payload = json.loads(open("/tmp/test.json").read())
>>> print payload
{}
```

Comment: Then I am receiving in the same line: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded, in the same line.

Comment: @christosh can you give your file `content` ? because I tried with sample `json` and its working fine

Comment: When trying payload = json.loads(open("request.json").read()) I got the same error.

Comment: create one `test.json` file and add content as `{}`, then this code will work. If you can give your file content, we can help better.

Comment: My json contains just {}. Actually I want to perform get not post.

Comment: @christosh I updated my answer, please try that, if you see `{}` in your file, then it might be some encoding issue, Are you using Windows or Linux ?

Comment: I am using Windows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133902/discussion-between-lafada-and-christosh).

Comment: can you give `cat request.json` output ?

Comment: @christosh A `GET` request cannot send JSON data in the HTML body

Answer (score 3):

> expected string or buffer

open() returns a file.

And there's a difference between `json.load()` and `json.loads()` (the second accepts a string, not a file)

Besides, I don't think the `json.dumps()` is necessary

Answer (score 2):

You are using [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) but attempting to load a file. You need to use [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) instead.

```
payload = json.load(open("request.json"))
```

Comment: Then I am receiving in the same line: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: @christosh then your `json` file is not valid `json format`, please check its format in some validator

Comment: My json contains just {}. Actually I want to perform get not post.